# Default Nullable Parameter in .net6 Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to learn .NET Identity on a Udemy course. He uses .NET 5 but I'm trying it in .NET 6. He created 2 entities.

```cs
public class AppRole : IdentityRole<int>
{
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

When I tried these, in migrations ImagePath and Gender sections are **nullable=false** automatically.

```cs
ImagePath = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", **nullable: false**),
Gender = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)",** nullable: false**),
```

**Is this because the difference of SDK's ? **

Should I use ? to make ImagePath and Gender nullable like below?

```cs
public string? ImagePath { get; set; }

public string? Gender { get; set; }
```

What is the proper way to get rid of this?

Should I remove the migrations and then create db again after add ? to properties.

> CS8618 - Non-nullable variable must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring it as nullable.

Comment: You can either disable the [Nullable context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts) if you don't want to use the [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) feature or add the `?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .NET 5 and earlier, all reference types are nullable and, in EF, you have to specify that the corresponding column is not null using an attribute or the fluent API in the `DbContext`. In .NET 6 and later, reference types are non-nullable by default and you specify that they are nullable by appending the `?` to the type. In this context, `string?` in .NET 6 is equivalent to `string` in .NET 5. You should make that change and rebuild the database or apply a new migration.