# The property on entity type cannot be used for objects of type Nullable1 with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

The line `dataContext.Entry(this).Property(property).IsModified = true;` is causing this error below.  This doesn't happen with non foreign key properties.  Any clue why?

> The property 'RankingId' on entity type 'TeamOrganizationSeason'
> cannot be used for objects of type Nullable1 because it is a
> property for objects of type Nullable1.

```
    public class TeamOrganizationSeason 
    {
        public int? RankingId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RankingId")]
        public Ranking Ranking { get; set; }

        public void IsUpdated(TeamOrganizationSeason teamOrganizationSeason, DataContext dataContext)
        {
            Update(RankingId, teamOrganizationSeason.RankingId, dataContext, t => t.RankingId);
        }

        private void Update(double? current, double? original, DataContext dataContext, Expression<Func<TeamOrganizationSeason, double?>> property)
        {
            if (current != original)
            {
                var state = dataContext.Entry(this).State;
                dataContext.TeamOrganizationSeasons.Attach(this);
                dataContext.Entry(this).Property(property).IsModified = true;
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you also attach the OnModelCreating of the dataContext?

Comment: I dont have it setup between TeamOrganizationSeason and Ranking in that method

Comment: Looking at efcore code this error is related to `DbEntityEntry_WrongGenericForProp` so check it your self or give us more details to help

Comment: I think as you have defined RankingId nullable, defining ranking as nullable should solve:  `public Ranking? Ranking { get; set; }`

Comment: That's the difference between .Net6 an 7 (if you are using these versions) and previous versions.

Comment: 'Ranking' is already nullable, its an object?  This isn't EF Core, it's EF 6.

Comment: >'Ranking' is already nullable, no in ef6 it is not by default nullable!

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74628976/default-nullable-parameter-in-net6-entity-framework)

Comment: Yes it is.  If I create a new object of TeamOrganizationSeason, Ranking is NULL.

Comment: Sure you can set the instance value to null! But being a nullable property is something else. Thats why you can define reference fields as nullable in .Net6. They are called `Nullable Reference Types`

Comment: I updated to langversion 8.0, put the question mark and still happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250143/discussion-between-md-zand-and-mike-flynn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had to do not with nullable issues but with different types.  An `int` being sent instead of a `double` was causing this error.  So we made it generic and all is well.

**Causing Code Error**

```
if (!requestedType.IsAssignableFrom(propertyType))
            {
                throw Error.DbEntityEntry_WrongGenericForProp(
                    propertyName, declaringType.Name, requestedType.Name, propertyType.Name);
            }
```

**Generic**

```
  private void Update<T>(double? current, double? original, DataContext dataContext, Expression<Func<TeamOrganizationSeason, T>> property)
            {
                if (current != original)
                {
                    if (dataContext.Entry(this).State == EntityState.Detached)
                    {
                        dataContext.TeamOrganizationSeasons.Attach(this);
                    }
                    dataContext.Entry(this).Property(property).IsModified = true;
                };
            }
```